# Swift WKWebView doesn't get initialised and causing unexpected nil error

Tags: ios, swift, null

I'm trying to get a rich text editor for iOS in Swift working. I do however get the following error:

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

When running this piece of code:

```
public var text: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let text = text else { return }
        if editorView.isLoading {
            textToLoad = text
        } else {
            editorView.evaluateJavaScript("richeditor.insertText(\"\(text.htmlEscapeQuotes)\");", completionHandler: nil)
            placeholderLabel.isHidden = !text.htmlToPlainText.isEmpty
        } 
    }
}
```

The error appears at the line
`if editorView.isLoading {`.

This is why I suppose that the editorView doesn't get initialised. It should however be initialised as you can see in the init method:

```
private var editorView: WKWebView!

public override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {

    placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.65)

    guard let bundlePath = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "Resources", ofType: "bundle"),
        let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath),
        let scriptPath = bundle.path(forResource: "RichTextEditor", ofType: "js"),
        let scriptContent = try? String(contentsOfFile: scriptPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let htmlPath = bundle.path(forResource: "RichTextEditor", ofType: "html"),
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        else { fatalError("Unable to find javscript/html for text editor") }

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(
        WKUserScript(source: scriptContent,
                     injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd,
                     forMainFrameOnly: true
        )
    )

    editorView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)


    super.init(frame: frame)

    [RichTextEditor.textDidChange, RichTextEditor.heightDidChange].forEach {
        configuration.userContentController.add(WeakScriptMessageHandler(delegate: self), name: $0)
    }

    editorView.navigationDelegate = self
    ...
    editorView.scrollView.delegate = self

    addSubview(placeholderLabel)

    ...

    addSubview(editorView)
    editorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([...])

    editorView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Is the init method not called? Or am I overseeing something?

The class in which this all happens has the following signature:

`public class RichTextEditor: UIView, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {`

Any input on how I can fix this issue is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that I had two initialisers in my file and that the code was not written for use with storyboards. Only the `init?(coder:)` was called when using storyboards, so this is the reason why the editorView wasn't initialised. I just moved all code from the:

`override init(frame: CGRect)`

initialiser to the

`required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)`

initialiser and this fixed the issue for me.